# Deploy VSTO Document solution to Excel 2003

Tags: c#, ms-office, vsto, office-2003

We have an Excel workbook which has c# VSTO code in it and two .NET DLLs that sit behind it. The spreadsheet used to work for all users in the organisation.

Recently our IT department had a problem with the OU which deleted all user accounts. The accounts were restored but since then users in our London office have not had the added functionality when they load the spreadsheet. Only users in the New York office and one developer (who has compiled the solution since) can use the functionality.

The files are all held in one directory on a shared network drive.

We have adjusted the manifest to reflect this location.

We have added the directory as a trusted site for code access security on the machine.

The office 2003 PIAs are installed and working as we have another application level extension installed on the machines and this is working correctly.

The .NET framework 3.5 is installed on all machines - as evidenced by the application extension.

VSTO 2005 SE Runtime is installed.

We've followed several how-to's from the internet to no avail, including:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332051.aspx#8

We have a suspicion that there is a security problem as the first line of our code is a logging message and this is not being hit.

No error message is given by excel, the spreadsheet opens and is usable but there is no access to any code and all buttons are disabled.

Any help would be massively appreciated as we've spent many hours trying to figure this out!

Thanks

***************EDIT******************************

Here's the actual cause of the problem from my IT Dept:

```
...was caused by the Organisational Unit container they were held in being 
deleted. This was restored and group memberships and distribution lists access
for individual accounts were then added manually
```

Comment: Did you grant permission to the additional dlls? The tutorial you point to is great, but works only if the add-in is the only dll.

Comment: Thanks Mahias,  we granted permission to the directory which contains all the DLLs.

Comment: Did you check event log and/or the output of fuslogvw.exe? How about simply re-deploying your app or calling the repair of the MSI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that over the weekend IT had downgraded all our versions of Excel from Professional to Standard. Not all VSTO works in Excel Standard, but it doesn't tell you this, it just doesn't work.

After upgrading we're all happy again!

Cheers